# SwiftUI picker with no title

Tags: swift, swiftui, uipickerview, picker

I'm trying to add a simple picker functionality by SwiftUI. Essentially the outcome I'm looking for is something like this:
[image]

When clicking on the arrow, it should take user to a new view where they select the required unit.

I tried something like this:

```
var units = ["ltr", "usg", "impg"]

@State private var selectedUnit = 0

var body: some View {
    Form {
        Section {
            VStack {
                Picker(selection: $selectedUnit, label: Text("")) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< units.count) {
                        Text(self.units[$0])
                        
                    }
                }.frame(width: 42)
            }
            
        }
    }.navigationBarTitle("Select unit")
}
```

But the as soon as this is wrapped in a form, it requires the title etc. and takes up too much space. I simply want to have the units as my base view. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: It is not clear what do you mean. Would you provide more details on what do you try to achieve, maybe some mockup?

Comment: So basically the user should be able to change the units from kg to ltr, usg or impg. To do this they should click on the arrow next to kg (see screen shot above) and that would take them to a new navigation controller where they select the unit. They then tap back to get back to main view. Essentially I believe this is the new default iOS picker replacing the wheelPicker? Basically like any picker in the iOS settings app

Comment: Ok, that's how it works in Form, so what's wrong?

Comment: So basically I only want the selectable element. The space I have in the stack is only around 40 point wide but with the form you need to supply a title e.g ‘units’ etc. All I want is the actual unit label and the arrow

Comment: Then just do it manually NavigationLink and List in destination view.

Comment: Sure can do. Just wondered if there was a way to utilise the Picker element as it had a fair amount of built in functionality. But that’s cool if not possible

Answer (score 8):

```
Picker("", selection: $data) {
    ForEach(data, id:\self) { child in
        Text(child)
    }
}
.pickerStyle(InlinePickerStyle())
.labelsHidden()
```

Try `.labelsHidden()`

Comment: Not a hack API at all :)

Answer (score 3):

Pass an `EmptyView` instance as the label of `Picker` to hide the title at top:

```
Picker(selection: $selectedUnit, label: EmptyView()) {
    ForEach(0 ..< units.count) {
        Text(self.units[$0])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var body: some View {
    Picker("Select a number", selection: $selectedNumber) {
        ForEach(0..<10) {
            Text("\($0)")
        }
    }
    .labelsHidden()        
}
```